# How do I implement the wrapping property of a caesar cypher?

Tags: c, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am coding in "C", and I am implementing the caesar cypher, and the value of each letter must remain within the bounds of capital letters (if the letter is uppercase) or lowercase letters (if the letter is lowercase) on the ASCII chart. How do I account for the case where the decimal value of some uppercase character in ASCII is shifted to a number exceeding 90 ('Z' in ASCII) or the decimal value of a lowercase character in ASCII is shifted to a number exceeding 122 ('z' in ASCII)?

Comment: use the mod operator

Comment: ...along with some addition and subtraction.

Comment: Hint: `int c = 'E'; printf("%d\n", c - 'A');` prints `4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edited answer to not give away entire solution after noticing this is for CS50)

Assuming `plaintext` is a char array containing the phrase you wish to encrypt using the caesar cipher and `shiftValue` is the number of places you wish to rotate the plain alphabet, below are
pieces of code addressing your question:

```
(plaintext[i] - 65 + shiftValue) % 26 + 65 // adjust for uppercase letters
(plaintext[i] - 97 + shiftValue) % 26 + 97 // adjust for lowercase letters
```

Let's first consider what we're doing when we adjust for uppercase letters. Let's say that the letter we're currently encrypting (`plaintext[i]`) is 'Y' and our shift/rotation value is 2. For right now, assume the uppercase alphabet is enumerated as 0 through 25 i.e. A = 0, B = 1,..., Y = 24, Z = 25. Now let's shift the alphabet by 2. Then, A = 2, B = 3,..., Y = 26, Z = 27. However, we only have alphabetical characters enumerated 0 through 25, so what we need to do to "wrap" the shift (i.e. make sure that the corresponding numerical value of 'Y' is within the range [0, 25]) is take the value mod 26. Of course, uppercase characters in ASCII are enumerated 65 through 90, so to apply this logic, we convert the enumeration from [65, 90] to [0, 25] by subtracting 65 from the ASCII value of each uppercase letter. After we've applied the shift, we add 65 back to convert back to ASCII. The logic is the same for lowercase letters except the way in which lowercase characters are enumerated in ASCII is obviously different from uppercase characters.

Comment: Curious, why use `65` and not `'A'` in `(plaintext[i] - 65 + shiftValue) % 26 + 65`?

Comment: More needed assumptions to work right: `shiftValue >= 0` and `(plaintext[i] - 65 + shiftValue) <= INT_MAX`.

Comment: @chux - Reinstate Monica To answer your question, I used 65 to emphasize the enumeration of alphabetical characters in ASCII, which was used in my answer (and in case OP is not familiar chars in C). Also, I completely agree with you that the assumptions you presented are necessary, and they are addressed in the problem specification on the CS50 website: "Your program should work for all non-negative integral values of k less than 2^(31) - 26" (k is the shift value). I'm assuming the question is asked with respect to these assumptions since the post is tagged cs50. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Thanks for detailing your rational.  FWIW, it easy to work with all `k`.  Simple reduce `k`: `k = (k%26 +26)%26;`.

Answer (score 1):

Following is a snippet of code to provide a proof of principle algorithm for adjusting the value of a generated value so that it falls within the range of 'A' to 'Z' or 'a' to 'z'.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int entry;
    int work;
    char value;

    while (1)
    {
        printf("Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter \"0\" to quit ");
        scanf("%d", &entry);

        if (entry == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        if (entry > 'Z' && entry < 'a')         /* Allows adjustment down into the uppercase letter range */
        {
            value = entry - 'Z' + '@';
            printf("Entry value of %d adjusted to uppercase character %c\n", entry, value);
        }
        else if (entry > 'z')                   /* Allows adjustment down into the lowercase letter range */
        {
            work = entry;
            while (work > 148)
            {
                work -= 26;
            }

            value = work - 'z' + '`';
            printf("Entry value of %d adjusted to lowercase character %c\n", entry, value);
        }
        else if ((entry >= 'A' && entry <= 'Z') ||(entry >= 'a' && entry <= 'z'))
        {
            value = entry;
            printf("Entry value of %d is a valid character %c\n", entry, value);
        }
        else                                    /* Here the entered/derived integer value falls out of range */
        {
            printf("The entered integer cannot be evaluated to a valid character\n");
        }

    }

    printf("Goodbye!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

The manual entry of numbers simulates the type of values that might be returned from the cypher function.  The one premise to this algorithm is that the generated number would not be less than the ASCII value of 'A' (65).  Following is some sample tests of various values being entered.

```
@Una:~/C_Programs/Console/CheckBounds/bin/Release$ ./CheckBounds 
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 77
Entry value of 77 is a valid character M
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 100
Entry value of 100 is a valid character d
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 95
Entry value of 95 adjusted to uppercase character E
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 120
Entry value of 120 is a valid character x
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 132
Entry value of 132 adjusted to lowercase character j
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 256
Entry value of 256 adjusted to lowercase character d
Please enter an integer value between 65 and 128 or enter "0" to quit 0
Goodbye!
```

Give that a try to see if this generates the boundaries you are looking for.